# Calculate the improper integral and the Taylor series of $f(x) = \int_0^\infty {e^{-t}\over 1+x \cdot t} \,\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, taylor-expansion

For the given function: $$f(x) = \int_0^\infty {e^{-t}\over 1+x \cdot t} \,\mathrm dt$$
with $x>0$, calculate the Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

I tried different stuff, but I did not get very far. I would really appreciate any help for solution.

Answer (score 4):

By differentiating under the integral sign,
$$ f^{(n)}(0) = (-1)^n n!\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^n e^{-t}\,dt = (-1)^n n!^2$$
hence the Taylor series of $f(x)$ in a neighbourhood of the origin is given by:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n n!\, z^n. $$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n t^n\, dt = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^n\, dt = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n n! x^n.$$